# returning a value within a abstract method

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have a abstract class called temperature with the following

```
 public abstract class Temperature
 {     

private float value;
public Temperature(float v)
{
    value = v;
}

public final float getValue()
{
    return value;
}

public abstract Temperature toCelsius();
public abstract Temperature toFahrenheit();
}
```

then i have a Celcius and Fahrenheit class that extend from temperature, but for space sake ill show Celcius

```
  public class Celsius extends Temperature
   { 

      public Celsius(float t)
  {
    super(t);
  }


  public String toString()
  {
    // TODO: Complete this method
    return "";
  }


  @Override
  public Temperature toCelsius() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }


  @Override
  public Temperature toFahrenheit() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }
      }
```

so my main program creates a new celcius object as follows

```
      Temperature inputTemp = null , outputTemp = null;
      inputTemp = new Celsius(temp_val);
```

outputTemp is then assigned to inputemp calling the toFahrenheit method

```
      outputTemp = inputTemp.toFahrenheit();
```

the resulting answer is then placed in the toString method

```
      outputTemp.toString
```

As far as i know, the `Celcius` constructor uses the `Temperature` constructor to store the passed in parameter of `temp_val`. However, what gets me confused is that how do i return the converted value of `Celcius` to `Fahrenheit` with `inputTemp.toFahrenheit` method??
I tried returning `this.getValue() * 9 / 5 + 32`, but eclipse complains that since `getValue()` is a `float` method, i either have to change the Overriding method to `float`, or change `getValue()` a `Temperature`, but both dont really work....

Comment: cant you make return type of this to double ?public abstract Temperature toCelsius();
public abstract Temperature toFahrenheit();

Comment: At the moment you don't really implement those methods. They just return `null`.

Comment: @SanjayRajjadi no, you're not allowed to change the abstract method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Celsius`, `toCelsuis` should return `this` because the `Temperature` is already in celsius. The `toFahrenheit` method should return a new `Fahrenheit` instance :

```
@Override
public Temperature toCelsius() {
    return this;
}

@Override
public Temperature toFahrenheit() {
    return new Fahrenheit(this.getValue() * 9D / 5D + 32D);
}
```

And the other way around for the `Fahrenheit` class.

Comment: thank you! how about the toString method? would i just put super.toString?

Answer (score 1):

`toFahrenheit` returns a reference to `Temperature`.

You have only two concrete classes matching that return value: `Celsius` and `Fahrenheit` so you should return a new object of one of these classes. Presumably `Fahrenheit` is it seems to be the aim of your method so, for `Celsius` class, you should have something like:

```
@Override
  public Temperature toFahrenheit() {
    return new Fahrenheit( this.getValue() * 9.0 /5.0 +32.0 );
  }
```

And, as your class is already representing temperature in celsius:

```
@Override
 public Temperature toCelsius() {
   return this;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `toFahrenheit()` you need to return the current object of type Temperature like this,

```
@Override
public Temperature toFahrenheit() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return this;
```

}

you can get the converted resultant value like this,

```
Temperature inputTemp = null , outputTemp = null;
inputTemp = new Celsius(temp_val);

outputTemp = inputTemp.toFahrenheit();

float result=outputTemp.getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change the **toCelsius** and **toFahrenheit** methods to return a float rather than a temperature?

```
@Override
public Float toFahrenheit() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return (getValue() * 9.0 /5.0 +32.0 );
}
```

Also, does it really make sense to declare the methods **toFahrenheit** and **toCelcius** in the base class? Would you not rather declare **toFahrenheit** only in the Celcius class and **toCelcius** only in the Fahrenheit class?